# how to align an image cv::Mat or Iplimage

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a function that takes a pointer to an image as input, but the problem is that the image by the pointer looks like this:

[image]

How can I align it?

```
image.SetImagePtr(matWidth, matHeigth, m_originalImg.data);
```

Comment: can you share the docs of IplImage? Looks like a padding problem. OpenCV Mat has a .step variable which tells you the bytes per imag elie. If that is not equal to matWidth * bytePerPixel you will have to use the padding.

Comment: I found a solution, as described in the documentation for this function, the step that returned me the number of bytes should have been divisible by 4 and multiplied by 8, so I used resize() pixels that would be divisible by 4 "The total number of bits contained in a row, padding included. Using the value 0 (default) means that this size is computed from the buffer width and the pixel size plus a padding with the smallest possible value that leads to a multiple of 4 bytes (32 bits)." So image.SetImagePtr(matWidth, matHeigth, clonedMat.data, clonedMat.step1() * 8);